# Eliminar de la lista Jquery Preview Imagenes- Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Buenas estoy haciendo un preview de imagenes, y logro hacer el preview pero lo que no logro es borrar la imagen se la lista seleccionada, puedo borrarla del preview pero aun me sale que tengo 3 imagenes seleccionadas (o las que se hayan seleccionado, alli muestro el codigo html y js, solo me falta eliminar la imagen que seleccione el usuario ,tanto del preview como de la lista

html

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>
                    <div id="image-holder"></div>
                </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#image-holder").on('click','.thumb-image',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("selectedItem");
});

$("#btnDelete").on("click",function(){
$(".selectedItem").parent().remove();

});

        $("#imagenes").on('change', function() {
          //Get count of selected files
          var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
          var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
          var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
          var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
          image_holder.empty();
          if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
              //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
              for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) 
              {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {

                    var $img =  $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "thumb-image img-fluid"
                  });

                 $("<div>", {
                        "class":"images-block col-4"               
                  }).html($img).appendTo('#image-holder');
                }
                image_holder.show();
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
              }
            } else {
              alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
          } else {
            alert("Pls select only images");
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega HTML, CSS y lo que has intentado.

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta